# cakephp load child inside parent model array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Is there a way to use find or paginate to load child relation inside parent (array(0 => parent(0 => child)) instead of one at each index (array(0 => parent, 1=> child) in cakephp?

Comment: look at in the recursive notion , http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into Containable Behaviour.

See...
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html